# How to call java class from project B in project A

Tags: java, sh, classpath

I'm trying to move a class from project A to project B (which is in Maven dependencies of the project A) to reuse it in other pet projects. Currently, this class calls from project A in a Jenkins groovy file like this:

`sh("java ./mycoolproject/common/core/SomeUsefulClass.java "arg1" "arg2"")`

How can I call SomeUsefulClass class from project A via sh script, considering that it has been moved to project B?

I tried different combinations of calling this class with the classpath flag but what I'm getting is just: `Error: Could not find or load main class SomeUsefulClass`. I guess there should be some solution to load this class from the class path and make it available for the project B locally on Windows and on remote CI on Linux.

Comment: You will never call "java" on a ".java" file.  You would compile the ".java" file using "javac" then run in via "java -cp <classpath> <fully qualified class name> <args>"

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to add a dependency on B and just make the call in Java code?

Answer (score 0):

I can explain you some possibilities:

1. Hardcopy your class from project B into your other project A and edit the package path.
2. Create a Jar as dependency from your project B and include it in your project A.
   You can archive this with e.g. Maven or Gradle.